# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am using Android Studio 3.1.3. Gradle build sync failed. I used following method but there is no use of it. If there is any solution please tell me

1. `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`
2. Invalidate restart & caches
3. `multiDexEnabled` `true`
4. Adding `mavenLocal()` and `mavenCentral()`

   This is module level **build.gradle** file:

   ```
   android {
           compileSdkVersion 27
           defaultConfig {
               applicationId "com.developers.a_g.designapp"
               minSdkVersion 15
               targetSdkVersion 27
               buildToolsVersion '27.1.1'
               versionCode 1
               versionName "1.0"
               multiDexEnabled true
               testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           }
           buildTypes {
               release {
                   minifyEnabled false
                   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               }
           }
       }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree( dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
       implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
       implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
   }


    android {
           compileSdkVersion 27
           defaultConfig {
               applicationId "com.developers.a_g.designapp"
               minSdkVersion 15
               targetSdkVersion 27
               buildToolsVersion '27.1.1'
               versionCode 1
               versionName "1.0"
               multiDexEnabled true
               testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           }
           buildTypes {
               release {
                   minifyEnabled false
                   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
               }
           }
       }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree( dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1'
       implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
       implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
       implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
       implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
   }
   ```

---

This is project level **build.gradle** file:

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {

            jcenter()
            google()


            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: have you tried adding `google()`?

Comment: Can you share your app level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: close project remove from Open  Recent, Build clean project, rebuild project.

Comment: add `jcenter()`  before  `google()`.

Comment: @WarrenFaith-yes i have added google

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel added jcenter() before google but not works

Comment: post your module and app's gradle files here.

Comment: show project level `build.gradle`.

Comment: change build tool from buildToolsVersion '27.1.1' to buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'. check my answer

Comment: @amoljunghare got point `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First **make sure** that you using:

```
targetSdkVersion 27
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

And your gradle be like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        //..
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //..
    }
}
```

And also update design implementation like below:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

You get this error because com.android.support:design-v7 does not exist it exist without -v7, also you can check support libraries [in this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) any time to make sure you are using the correct library.

Comment: @amoljunghare just remove -v7 from com.android.support:design, you get this error because com.android.support:design-v7 does not exist it exist without -v7, also update build tools to 27.0.3 and it will be fixed

Answer (score 2):

You should add `google()` repository to your dependencies

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       google()
       jcenter() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't**

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1'
 buildToolsVersion '27.1.1'
```

**Do**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Make sure, you added below

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }

        }
    }
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Build`**.

Comment: now it says failed to find build tools revision 27.1.1 & All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;27.1.1

Comment: @amoljunghare use `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`

Comment: change also buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

Comment: @amoljunghare Solved this yet??

Answer (score 0):

Add the maven URL in all projects section as well and sync the gradle or try removing one by one external libraries and sync the gradle hope it helps

```
allprojects { repositories { google() jcenter()maven :"http://www.google.com" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct form
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to **Android Studio 3.3** destroyed all my projects.

This was one of the problems today I ran into. And after wasting too much time to find a solution, here is the working gradle. By the time I fixed this, I had forgotten what actually I was working on. I really wonder why Google always ship their Android Studio with broken gradle files. Seems like Google engineers even themselves don't know how to write proper gradle, and nobody QAs Android Studio before its final release.

Module level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.journaldev.okhttp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```

And the project level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```