# Unable to resolve dependency for design:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

sorry for my bad English.
I tried to build my project but I get this error and i couldn't find any solution for this problem in internet.
also i must say gradle offline work is off.

[image: Error Image]

How can resolve this error ?

my problem is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189234/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportdesign-v727-1-1) problem.because in that problem he used

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design-v7:27.1.1'
```

and "-v7" should not be there. also i used

```
targetSdkVersion 27
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

and

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

in my program. but problem is still exists :(

Comment: probably you didn't add Google repo to the list of repositories.

Comment: Can you find your solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691858/failed-to-resolve-com-android-support-design25-4-0/44691903

Comment: share whole gralde file code

Comment: Hello danial. Try to use VPN because I'm guessing that you got iranian IP.

Comment: Disable offline build and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue usually happens when the Android Studio is not able to download that dependency. That can be due to many reasons like in my case where the Maven2 and jcenter repositories are blocked in Company.

> Android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7

So what can you do is like check this folder
and check which all versions are available to you in the SDK, use either one of those versions,  So instead of downloading from repository studio will take that lib from SDK.

let me know if it will help to you.

Comment: i changed version of design to "26.0.0-alpha1" and it's worked  for me.
but i can't understand why this problem happened. because i can change version of "appcompat" and android-studio will download it without any problem but when i change "design" version i will get that error.